# Find a text string, modify a text string in jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I am parsing JSON in jquery and i wish to remove some text from the "name" field on a certain element.

I am trying the following code but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$('#content ul li:contains("Industrial Average")').replace("");
```

Here is a fiddle to the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/c2VeD/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#content ul li:contains("Industrial Average")')
 .html($('#content ul li:contains("Industrial Average")')
 .text().replace("Industrial Average", ""));
```